# Почему не меняется ширина div?

Tags: html, css, html5

Всем привет, есть проблема. И она связана с тем что div c id panel не меняет свою ширину.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>SimpleNumberGeneratorWeb 1.2 - number generator</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>
        <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png">
        <hr id="line">
    </h1>

<center>
    <div id="panel">
        <h3>Random number:</h3>
        <h2 id="result">0</h2>
        <span>min:</span>
        <input type="text" id="min">
        <span>max:</span>
        <input type="text" id="max"><br>
        <button onclick="generate();">Generate!</button>
    </div>
</center>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#logo{
    margin-top: -25px;
}

#line{
    margin-top: -25px;
}

#panel{
    border: black solid 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

input{
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50px;
}

button{
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#panel{
    width:500;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У величин размеров в CSS **обязательно** должны быть указаны [единицы измерения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units).

В данном случае, видимо, предполагаются пиксели:
`width:500`  `width: 500px`